# Java Pressing 2 Keys at Once

Tags: java, key-bindings

I am making a game, and when a user presses a key it works when they press another key the previous key stops working, and the newly pressed key takes over. Using the following blocks as examples, is this a Java thing, or does it have to do with my code?

```
keyboard.setEvent("LEFT", new AbstractAction(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        // Moves an object left
    }
});

keyboard.setEvent("SPACE", new AbstractAction(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        // Creates and object and moves it upwards
    }
});
```

This method (called above) creates the events.

```
public void setEvent(String key, AbstractAction act){
    // Key Pressed
    comp.
            getInputMap(Room.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).
            put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), "do" + key + "Action");
    comp.
            getActionMap().
            put("do" + key + "Action", act);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried it in a text editor?  Holding one key will repeat that character, holding a second key without releasing the first will start repeating the second character.

Comment: @Doorknob I tried adding a KeyListener, but I can only place it within a JFrame